Indefinite article with the names of arithmetic operations
Can I use "an" with the word "addition" (or any other arithmetic operation) in order to identify just one specific operation? For example, "to do an addition"? It sounds a bit weird to my ear.

An article is optional, depending on context (e.g., if an operator is used as noun or adjective), but certainly is correct to use. Here are some examples that are grammatically correct and common colloquially.

This is an addition problem to solve.
Solve this addition problem.
The sum of four and eight is 12.
Give me a sum equal to its product. [2+2, 2x2]
A reciprocal is a multiplicative inverse.
What is two's reciprocal?

Also, with operators used for non-mathematical purposes:

We need an addition to the house for our large family.
She bought a plot in a division in Hartford.
Gadamer was an exponent of biblical hermeneutics.

[But not, "The fallen tree in our garden is a natural log." Though the grammar is acceptable, the pun is atrocious.]

But if I'm referring to the trunk of a real tree (not a logarithm, of course), can it  be "a natural log"?

@Artem, yes, that was just a silly pun. Sorry about any confusion.

Got it :) No problem!

It seems odd because it would be natural in most situations to use the verb "add" instead of the phrase "do an addition"
In non-mathematical contexts it might be reasonable to "do an addition".  It might also be possible in some very elementary school contexts, in which "an addition" is a short way of saying "a maths question like '29+36'".  It's not wrong, but the contexts in which you would say "do an addition" are pretty limited.
The specific term for a list of terms that are added together is "a sum", and this is generally preferred over "an addition"

Add 7 and 8  (instead of Do an addition of 7 and 8)


A sum (not 'an addition') of rational numbers is always rational.


I would go so far as to say that the problem is not with the article but with the verb "do." Non-mathematical contexts use articles with other verbs often enough: "This baby is a welcome addition to the family."

[A response from a mathematician]
It would be perfectly acceptable in mathematical discourse to speak of performing an addition (or a multiplication, etc.). The case of performing certain exponentiations is different: one takes (or extracts) an nth root.

Thank you so much  for your answer!
